# Python : Using regex to select a text in a big text

Tags: python, regex

```
s="""set(Q)
    {
information 1
    }

set(CP)
    {
information 2
    }
set(R)
    {
information 3
    }
"""
```

how can a make a function f that takes as input a identifier like (CP , R) to select exactely set

example :   f("R") ------> set(R)
    {
information 3
    }

NB : Whene I used this code :  it gave me : 
set(Q)
    {
information 1
    }

set(CP)
    {
information 2
    }
set(R)

```
import re
def f(identifier) :

re.findall(r"set\({}\.+set)".format(identifier),s)
```

Comment: you might want to look at escaping characters int your identifier. not sure what yourproblem is- does it work? are there errors? how do you call it? Also-when you are at it,please fix indentation

Comment: Thank you Patrick Artner for your reply , don't worry about identation, I want to match exactly a set using a identifier you can see the example that i did

Comment: Your code currently throws an IndentationError - you _should_ worry about indentation

Comment: I'm agree, I know I need help to write pattern with Regex  to match exactly a set using a identifier from the string s ( above).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use re.finditer to get the index of your search pattern, then looping through string until *}*, saving at the same time content you need

```
import re

s = """set(Q)
    {
information 1
    }

set(CP)
    {
information 2
    }
set(R)
    {
information 3
    }
set(Q)
    {
information 13
    }
"""
# print (s)


def f(identifier=''):
    var_to_return = []
    search_result = re.finditer(r'set\('+identifier+r'\)', s)
    for result in search_result:
        str_to_save = ''
        idx = result.span()[1]
        while True:
            str_to_save += s[idx]
            idx += 1
            if str_to_save[-1] == '}':
                break

        var_to_return.append(str_to_save)
    return var_to_return


print(f('Q'))
```

prints an array with elements found:

> ['\n    {\ninformation 1\n    }', '\n    {\ninformation 13\n    }']